# How to create type safe "Recursive" type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing

I want to create typed tree sctructure, passing root and child nodes schemas. I expect required properties to be required and optional not to be required, according to schemas, as it must be. However my type test doesn't pass. Here's my piece of code:

```js
type TypedTree<TRootSchema, TChildSchema = TRootSchema> =
  {
    [K in keyof TRootSchema]: TRootSchema[K]
  } | {
    [key: string]: TypedTree<TChildSchema>
  }

const $typeTest = <T>(v: T) => v

// @ts-expect-error Required properies must be present
$typeTest<TypedTree<{ a: number }>>({ })
//  It fails
```

Comment: Isn't `{ [K in keyof TRootSchema]: TRootSchema[K] }` just the same as `TRootSchema`?

Comment: yeah, whatever, question is still remain

Answer (score 0):

I've just come up with working solution, need to explicitly pass possible child node keys, then types will work. However I would like not to do this, I would like either typescript  infer child keys by himself, either anything else so that code in question just to work.

Here's current code:

```js
type Schema = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>

type SchemaTuple = [Schema, Schema]

type TypedTree2<
  TSchema extends Schema | SchemaTuple,
  TNodeKeys extends string = never,
  _TInferredRootSchema_ extends Schema = TSchema extends SchemaTuple ? TSchema[0] : TSchema,
  _TInferredChildSchema_ extends Schema = TSchema extends SchemaTuple ? TSchema[1] : TSchema
> = {
  [K in keyof _TInferredRootSchema_]: _TInferredRootSchema_[K]
} & {
  [K in TNodeKeys]?: TypedTree2<_TInferredChildSchema_, TNodeKeys>
}

$typeTest<TypedTree2<[{ a: number }, { a?: number }], 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'>>({
  a: 1,
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: {
        foo: {
          a: 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

// @ts-expect-error Required properties must be present
$typeTest<TypedTree2<{ a: number }>>({ })

$typeTest<TypedTree2<{ a: number }>>({ a: 1 })

$typeTest<TypedTree2<{ a: number }, 'a_2' | 'a_3'>>({
  a: 1,
  a_2: {
    a: 2,
    a_3: {
      a: 3
    }
  }
})

$typeTest<TypedTree2<{ a: number }, 'a_2' | 'a_3'>>({
  a: 2,
  // @ts-expect-error Child node keys must satisfy second type parameter
  unknown_key: { a: 3}
})
```